# Cannot get data from SQLite database

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

I am trying to runn the following query:

```
SELECT nfc_film.title, nfc_film.film_id, nfc_film.description, nfc_film.release_year, nfc_film.rating, nfc_film.last_update, nfc_category.name
  FROM nfc_film
JOIN nfc_film_category
  ON nfc_film.film_id = nfc_film_category.film_id
JOIN nfc_category
  ON nfc_film_category.category_id = nfc_category.category_id  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

This works if i put it into 'DB Browser for SQLite', the right fields are returned.

But when trying to implement this in PHP it doesn't work:

```
$filmQuery = "
SELECT nfc_film.title, nfc_film.film_id, nfc_film.description, nfc_film.release_year, nfc_film.rating, nfc_film.last_update, nfc_category.name
  FROM nfc_film
JOIN nfc_film_category
  ON nfc_film.film_id = nfc_film_category.film_id
JOIN nfc_category
  ON nfc_film_category.category_id = nfc_category.category_id ";

if($search_term && $category){
  $filmQuery .= "
  WHERE
    nfc_film.title LIKE :searchterm
  AND
    nfc_category.name = :category";
} else if ($search_term && !$category) {
  $filmQuery .= "
  WHERE
    nfc_film.title LIKE :searchterm";
} else if (!$search_term && $category) {
  $filmQuery .= "
  WHERE
    nfc_category.name = :category";
}

$filmQuery .= " LIMIT 10 OFFSET :page";
```

When neither `category` or `searchterm` are found, then this resolves to:

```
SELECT nfc_film.title, nfc_film.film_id, nfc_film.description, nfc_film.release_year, nfc_film.rating, nfc_film.last_update, nfc_category.name
      FROM nfc_film
    JOIN nfc_film_category
      ON nfc_film.film_id = nfc_film_category.film_id
    JOIN nfc_category
      ON nfc_film_category.category_id = nfc_category.category_id  LIMIT 10 OFFSET :page
```

I then prepare, bind, and execute the query:

```
$sqlGetFilms = $dbConn->prepare($filmQuery);
$sqlGetFilms->bindParam(':searchterm', $sqlSearchTerm);
$sqlGetFilms->bindParam(':category', $category);
$sqlGetFilms->bindParam(':page', $page);
$sqlGetFilms->execute();
$query = $sqlGetFilms->fetchAll();
```

When noth `searchterm` and `category` are found, records are returned. But any other situation that appears in this code does not return any records, even though they appear when run in 'DB Browser for SQLite'

EDIT:
I have tried hardcoding

```
SELECT nfc_film.title, nfc_film.film_id, nfc_film.description, nfc_film.release_year, nfc_film.rating, nfc_film.last_update, nfc_category.name
      FROM nfc_film
    JOIN nfc_film_category
      ON nfc_film.film_id = nfc_film_category.film_id
    JOIN nfc_category
      ON nfc_film_category.category_id = nfc_category.category_id 
      WHERE
        nfc_film.title LIKE '%k%' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

and nothing was returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find that when you only use one or the other terms that you get an error which is something like trying to bind to a non-existent variable.
This (I think) is down to where you conditionally build the SQL, you may have `:searchterm` or `:category` or both - BUT you always try and bind to both of them.

So instead, if there is a value to bind - then bind each term individually...

```
if(!empty($search_term)){
    $sqlGetFilms->bindParam(':searchterm', $sqlSearchTerm);
} 
if(!empty($category)) {
    $sqlGetFilms->bindParam(':category', $category);
}
```